# Include Flutter in settings.gradle.kts

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, flutter

Currently I'm looking into including a Flutter module into an existing Android Application.
Therefore I decided to take a look at add Flutter to an existing apps guide [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps#make-the-host-app-depend-on-the-flutter-module).

The guide assumes a `Gradle` settings file.
While we have converted to `Kotlin` settings file.

```
include ':app'                                          // assumed existing content
setBinding(new Binding([gradle: this]))                 // new
evaluate(new File(                                      // new
        settingsDir.parentFile,                         // new
        'my_flutter/.android/include_flutter.groovy'    // new
))
```

Does anyone know the equivalent Kotlin configuration?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find answer yet?

Comment: Hey did you guys find any answer?

Comment: you should change `include ':app'` to `include("app")`

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29366 It is answered here.